# Loopback: getting model changes inside model hook

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

On model PUT, I need to make custom validation, based on its original value.
Inside beforeUpdate model hook I can access 'next' function, 'request body' object (as beforeUpdate arguments) and updated model itself via 'this' keyword.

Is there any way to get pristine model or its changes, without querying it from DB?

Is it even possible to update current model inside model hooks (because changing 'this' properties doesn't take effect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a LoopBack developer.*

> Is there any way to get pristine model or its changes, without querying it from DB?

No, that's not possible.

Take a look at the code of `updateAttributes()` in [loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/c1af74dac5ae8aeedd039272aa7f36fb4edf34ad/lib/dao.js#L1228-L1239), which is called when you make a request to `PUT /models/:id`:

```
inst.setAttributes(data);

inst.isValid(function (valid) {
  if (!valid) {
    if (cb) {
      cb(new ValidationError(inst), inst);
    }
  } else {
    inst.trigger('save', function (saveDone) {
      inst.trigger('update', function (done) {
        // etc.
```

The model is updated before executing any hooks.

Comment: One question. Is any way to access request headers like accesstoken or userID with model hooks? PLease see question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927791/access-request-headers-from-beforesave-model-hook