# Loopback get http context in an overriden built-in method

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to use a custom endpoint for POST /images; so what i thought i could override the create method of a model; this is how I'm doing it:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');


function overrideImageApiMethods(app){
    var Image = app.models.Image,
        create = Image.create;

    Image.create = function create(data, clb){
       var context = loopback.getCurrentContext();
    };
 }

module.exports = overrideImageApiMethods;
```

I would like to get the response object like you would do it in express; I found the getCurrentContext method returns null in the example above.

What is the correct way to about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loopback.getCurrentContext()` - returns not exactly what you assume.
Its the per request storage - the wrapper for [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.org/package/continuation-local-storage). 
But for me it returns null too.

So to access context with its req & res, you should dig deeper to [context implementation](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/pull/337/files) or use [domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927791/access-request-headers-from-beforesave-model-hook/26989324#26989324)!

Answer (score -1):

See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Customizing+models#Customizingmodels-Changetheimplementationofbuilt-inmethods

```
var Image = app.models.Image;
...
Image.create = function(...) {
  //your logic     
};
```

Comment: That's not the question. I need to get the http context

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, then you should create a remote method with the same name.

    ...
    Image.create = function() { ... }
    ...
    Image.remoteMethod('create', function() { ... })
    ...

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/loopbackjs/context$20object$20override/loopbackjs/qo-WuE9ways/igKfmxdrTGEJ

Comment: that's what i ended up doing; I thought there is nicer way